# Internet works perfectly - except Google

Tags: networking

After installing the proprietary drivers for my Ethernet and WiFi by Realtek, my Internet is as fast as it was on Windows before - except when I'm using Google. Loading any Google site is even slower than the normal internet speed with the default drivers. Even then the problem was there.
This only happens to Google, independent of the browser (Firefox, Chromium, even ELinks says *Searching Host* for at least 20s)

Does any one of you have the same problems? Does anyone know a fix?

```
$ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse b8:70:f4:d0:52:08  
          inet Adresse:192.168.0.100  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Maske:255.255.255.0
          inet6-Adresse: fe80::ba70:f4ff:fed0:5208/64 Gültigkeitsbereich:Verbindung
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
          RX packets:22659 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:17586 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1000 
          RX-Bytes:20225533 (20.2 MB)  TX-Bytes:1998427 (1.9 MB)

lo        Link encap:Lokale Schleife  
          inet Adresse:127.0.0.1  Maske:255.0.0.0
          inet6-Adresse: ::1/128 Gültigkeitsbereich:Maschine
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metrik:1
          RX packets:32666 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:32666 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:0 
          RX-Bytes:2372372 (2.3 MB)  TX-Bytes:2372372 (2.3 MB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse d0:df:9a:eb:af:28  
          inet Adresse:192.168.0.101  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Maske:255.255.255.0
          inet6-Adresse: fe80::d2df:9aff:feeb:af28/64 Gültigkeitsbereich:Verbindung
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
          RX packets:2442 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:617 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1000 
          RX-Bytes:726915 (726.9 KB)  TX-Bytes:61394 (61.3 KB)

$ping6 -c 2 google.com
unknown host             #I'm not using IPv6 yet

$ping -c 2 google.com
PING www.google.com (173.194.116.50) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 173.194.116.50: icmp_req=1 ttl=56 time=10.0 ms
64 bytes from 173.194.116.50: icmp_req=2 ttl=56 time=22.0 ms

--- www.google.com ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 15014ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 10.001/16.011/22.021/6.010 ms
```

It SAYS that it only lasted 16ms, but it took quite a while to resolve the host...

```
$host -v google.com
Trying "google.com"
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 1812
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 11, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.     297 IN  A   173.194.116.40
google.com.     297 IN  A   173.194.116.34
google.com.     297 IN  A   173.194.116.36
google.com.     297 IN  A   173.194.116.37
google.com.     297 IN  A   173.194.116.33
google.com.     297 IN  A   173.194.116.32
google.com.     297 IN  A   173.194.116.38
google.com.     297 IN  A   173.194.116.39
google.com.     297 IN  A   173.194.116.35
google.com.     297 IN  A   173.194.116.41
google.com.     297 IN  A   173.194.116.46

Received 204 bytes from 127.0.1.1#53 in 11 ms
Trying "google.com"
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
Trying "google.com"
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Comment: Done. But I'm not using IPv6

Comment: Did you try restarting your router?

Comment: My parents switch off the router to control my internet consumption. So YES.

Comment: Have you emptied your Cache? A corrupted cache has the same behavior as this.

Comment: What DNS you use? add `host -v google.com` too. If you don't use `google.com` maybe you should add the specific domain name.

Comment: Cache is empty. I'm using private mode and the cache gets emptied on quit. `host -v google.com` output added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were some extra parameters in the search engine. After changing it to `http://www.google.ch/search?q=%s` it's working fine.

Comment: Which DNS servers are you using, a custom DNS server or the DNS servers provided by your ISP? Google has public, free to use, DNS servers at 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 which are often faster than ISP servers; downside is, Google knows every website you go to, and can sell that data, whereas your ISP normally won't sell that data. So, speed, vs privacy, what's your preference?

Comment: ISP DNS. But it's fast enough now. When querying `google.com` it still takes ages, but when using the modified search engine it runs fast.

Comment: And, if you value privacy in search, suggest you abandon google and use https://ixquick.com (which is in the EU) or https://duckduckgo.com (US).

Answer (score 0):

After seeing the information, the only thing that struck my mind is that if you are using wired connection you should shut down the wireless. When you are using both connections against the same router, the system gets confused. This method should only be used if you have both input/output from the internet separated.

If you don't use wireless when you are connected using the wired connection you should be fine.

Comment: No effect. Btw. I'm ways too lazy to hit FnF8 when plugging the cable...